# Including an interaction term vs running a regression with a portion of the dataset

Tags: econometrics, interaction

I ran an ordered probit regression with the following equation:

(Eq.1) $$Y = B0 + B1 X1 + B2 NotPoor + Other controls$$

Where Y is a categorical variable, X1 is a continous variable and Not_Poor is dichotomous variable that takes the value of 1 if an individual is not poor and 0 otherwise.

I got and insignificant B1. Theory suggest, however, that relationship between X1 and Y should be stronger among the poor. To test this, I have contemplated two methods.

A) Keeping only the poor individuals of my dataset (i.e., running the line "keep if Not_Poor==0" in STATA) and running Eq.1 again.

B) Adding an interaction term between X1 and Not_Poor as follows: $$Y = B0 + B1 X1 + B2 NotPoor + B3 (NotPoor * X1) + Controls$$

In both cases, B1 is the effect of X1 on Y among the poor. However, I find that B1 is non-significant with method A and significant with method B.

My questions are:

i) What could explain this discrepancy?

ii) Under which circumstances should method A be prefered to method B and viceversa?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Subset analysis (method A) can lose power to find true associations, as it it based on fewer cases. If you expect that the effect of a continuous predictor like `X1` will differ depending on the value of another predictor, then an interaction term (method B) is a way to proceed.

With the interaction, however, you need to be very careful in how you interpret the coefficients. With the interaction the `B1` coefficient is for `X1` when `NotPoor` is at its reference level (0, "Poor"); `B2` is the difference associated with `NotPoor = 1` *when*  `X1 = 0`; you need to use `B3` along with the actual level of `X1` to evaluate the *extra* effect (beyond what you'd expect based on `B1` and `B2`) at other predictor combinations. Tests on the interaction coefficient `B3` address your hypothesis that the "relationship between X1 and Y should be stronger among the poor."

With an interaction you shouldn't be focused so much on the "significance" of the individual coefficients. To evaluate whether `X1` is associated with outcome you need to assess the *combination* of coefficients associated with it, including its interactions.